# Turning off page transition animations for Android's Intent.ACTION_PICK

Tags: java, android, android-activity

On Android, is it possible to launch an image picker and control its page transition animations?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {                
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}
```

For example, I'd like to be able to turn off the default transition to the list of photos when the user selects a specific album or hits the back button while the intent is showing individual images. Since this is an activity controlled by Android, I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Since this is an activity controlled by Android

Not really. Anyone can write an `ACTION_PICK` implementation. I imagine that there are dozens, if not hundreds, of these implementations pre-installed across the ~2 billion Android devices and ~20,000 device models. Plus, there can be others that the user installs from the Play Store or other app distribution channels.

> is it possible to launch an image picker and control its page transition animations?
>   For example, I'd like to be able to turn off the default transition to the list of photos when the user selects a specific album or hits the back button while the intent is showing individual images.

At most, you can control the activity transitions from your app to the `ACTION_PICK` activity. You have no control over whether the app that implements that activity uses transitions at all, has the concept of an "album", etc.

---

Also note that your `ACTION_PICK` request is broken:

- `ACTION_PICK` does not use a MIME type
- `ACTION_PICK` requires a `Uri` in the `Intent`, indicating what collection of stuff to pick from

See [the `ACTION_PICK` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK). In addition, [the documentation on picking a contact](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Contacts) demonstrates the use of `ACTION_PICK`.

If you replace `ACTION_PICK` with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, that would be supported, as it uses a MIME type and does not use a `Uri`.